# How to setup the stm32f4 real time clock(RTC) to get valid values in the sub second register?

Tags: arm, stm32f4, real-time-clock

I like to use my stm32f412 RTC at high resolution. For testing I use CubeMX code generator.
For reading the rtc timestamp I am using:

```
// get sub second
ss = (u16_t) LL_RTC_TS_GetSubSecond(RTC);
// 0x00HHMMSS in bcd format
t = LL_RTC_TIME_Get(RTC);
// 0xWWDDMMYY
d = LL_RTC_DATE_Get(RTC);
```

The rtc is using a 32.768kHz osc at PC14 & PC15(LSE input). The setup code looks like:

```
static LL_RTC_InitTypeDef const initData = {
    .HourFormat = LL_RTC_HOURFORMAT_24HOUR,
    /* prescaler values for LSE @ 32768 Hz */
    .AsynchPrescaler = 0x7F,
    .SynchPrescaler = 0x00FF
};

LL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
LL_RCC_ForceBackupDomainReset();
LL_RCC_ReleaseBackupDomainReset();

LL_RCC_LSE_Enable();

/* Wait untill LSE is ready */
while (LL_RCC_LSE_IsReady() != 1) {};

LL_RCC_SetRTCClockSource(LL_RCC_RTC_CLKSOURCE_LSE);

LL_RCC_EnableRTC();

if (LL_RTC_DeInit(RTC) != SUCCESS) {
    return -EIO;
}

if (LL_RTC_Init(RTC, (LL_RTC_InitTypeDef *)&initData) != SUCCESS) {
    return -EIO;
}

LL_RTC_EnableShadowRegBypass(RTC);
```

Guess I am missing some steps in the setup.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useing the right API function helps:

```
// get sub section
ss = (u16_t) LL_RTC_TIME_GetSubSecond(RTC);
// 0x00HHMMSS in bcd format
t = LL_RTC_TIME_Get(RTC);
// 0xWWDDMMYY
d = LL_RTC_DATE_Get(RTC);
```